# Remove label for in div

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, icons, picker

I am using icon picker in my cshtml. 
I use it with these codes in my page.

```
        <div class="form-group" id="kisayolikon" style="display: none">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Kisayol.KisayolIkon, new { @class = "IconPicker ", placeholder = _T("Kisayol Simgesi") })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kisayol.KisayolIkon)
        </div>
```

But when I click to button. Categories space comes with a label for (I added screenshot). I want to remove this label for with script or other method. I tried to do it with 
[in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBqIA.jpg)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#kisayolikon .floatlabel-wrapper").removeClass("floatlabel-wrapper");
        $("#kisayolikon .label-for").removeClass("label-for");
        $("#kisayolikon .label-floatlabel").removeClass("label-floatlabel");
        $("#kisayolikon .label").removeClass("label");
        $("kisayolikon label").remove();
        $("kisayolikon > label").remove();
        $(".kisayolikon").empty();
        $("kisayolikon > label").remove();
        $(".selector - category").empty();

        $("kisayolikon label").remove();

        });
```

but none of them worked. it is looks like this when I use inspect element.I want to remove these all label for and  from my div. (I added screenshoot too.)[with inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYzPd.jpg)

Comment: if possible, can you please share the code for full page so that it can be easily observed that where you have added these class in your form.

Comment: <script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="~/CKFinderScripts/ckfinder.js"></script>


using WEB.Admin.MvcUI.Infrastructure
@using WEB.Admin.MvcUI.Models.KisayolModels
model WEB.Admin.MvcUI.Models.KisayolModels.KisayolKaydet

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/lib/IconPicker/demo/demo.js"></script>

Only there are reference too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var local = $("name-of-element").parents("label");
$(local).remove();
```

Will remove the top label element.

Comment: I tried with this but not worked :(



        $(document).ready(function () {


            var local = $("kisayolikon").parents("label-for");
            $(local).remove();

            var local1 = $("floatlabel-wrapper").parents("label-for");
            $(local1).remove();
            }
   
   );
   
   
   
   
   

        $(document).ready(function () {


            var local = $("kisayolikon").parents("label");
            $(local).remove();

            var local1 = $("floatlabel-wrapper").parents("label");
            $(local1).remove();
            });

Comment: may the code that insert the label run after "$(document).ready". You need remove the label after it insert in your div. See the sequence of execution of your code. (Sorry my english)